# WKWebView constrains issue when keyboard pops up

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

When an input in `WKWebView` gets focused a constraints error pops up.

**Code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        let wv = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100));
        wv.loadHTMLString("<input type='text'/>", baseURL: nil); // it also can be select, it makes no difference
        view.addSubview(wv);
    }
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
2017-11-05 00:26:28.861439+0700 achievator[20048:75393577] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.     (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60c0000955e0 h=-&- v=-&- UIToolbar:0x7f8540419570.width ==
_UIInputViewContent:0x7f8540411830.width   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60c000095720 h=--& v=--& _UIInputViewContent:0x7f8540411830.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a9a0 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f854041b2d0]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8540402de0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a9f0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f854041b2d0.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8540402de0.trailing + 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000099a00 _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8540402de0.trailing == UIToolbar:0x7f8540419570.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000099aa0 H:|-(0)-[_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8540402de0]   (active, names: '|':UIToolbar:0x7f8540419570 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040000981a0 H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f854050ef70]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050e7f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040000981f0 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f854050ef70]-(>=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050e7f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040000999b0 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f8540512450'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f8540511660 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000099a00 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f8540512450'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f8540511660 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000094690 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6080001a9a00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading ==
_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050e7f0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c0000946e0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6080001a9a00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing ==
_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f8540511660.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000094780 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050e7f0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f854050f4c0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000094960 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f854050f4c0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050ea30]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000094a00 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050ea30]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f8540511480]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000094a50 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f8540511480]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f8540511660]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a6d0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001a9a00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)  (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f854041b2d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a770 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001a9a00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)  (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f854041b2d0 )>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040000981f0 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f854050ef70]-(>=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050e7f0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. 2017-11-05 00:26:28.863156+0700 achievator[20048:75393577] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.     (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60c0000955e0 h=-&- v=-&- UIToolbar:0x7f8540419570.width ==
_UIInputViewContent:0x7f8540411830.width   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60c000095720 h=--& v=--& _UIInputViewContent:0x7f8540411830.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a9a0 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f854041b2d0]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8540402de0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a9f0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f854041b2d0.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8540402de0.trailing + 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000099a00 _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8540402de0.trailing == UIToolbar:0x7f8540419570.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000099aa0 H:|-(0)-[_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f8540402de0]   (active, names: '|':UIToolbar:0x7f8540419570 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000098560 H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f8540510b40]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050ea30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000098650 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f8540510b40]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050ea30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040000999b0 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f8540512450'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f8540511660 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000099a00 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f8540512450'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f8540511660 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000094690 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6080001a9a00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading ==
_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050e7f0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c0000946e0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6080001a9a00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing ==
_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f8540511660.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000094780 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050e7f0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f854050f4c0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000094960 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f854050f4c0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050ea30]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000094a00 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050ea30]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f8540511480]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000094a50 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f8540511480]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f8540511660]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a6d0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001a9a00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)  (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f854041b2d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a770 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001a9a00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)  (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f854041b2d0 )>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000098650 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f8540510b40]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f854050ea30 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My assumption is this a bug in ios 11. The complaints are about the components in the button bar for the keyboard which are all using default values set by the os. I have run the same code on both ios 9 and ios 10 and get no error messages.

Comment: is there any solution in sight? Can this be fixed somehow? Getting the same on iOS 13 beta 5

Comment: If you just want to remove the white space at the bottom:

    `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: 
    UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
                self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
    }`


@swalkner If the offset was different than 0 you could get the content offset value in  `keyboardWillShowNotification` and set it accordingly in `keyboardWillHideNotification`

Answer (score 3):

Having the same issue. I'm running a clean project, vanilla setup and this issue comes up as soon as the webview keyboard gets focus. It seems to be a common issue, might just be a bug in iOS 11.

Also see:

[WKWebView LayoutConstraints issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993890/wkwebview-layoutconstraints-issue)

Comment: no way, still a but in 2022?...

Answer (score 2):

One or more constraints are not compatible at the same time when keyboard is open.

Instead of doing frame by hand, try setting constraints to ur WKWebView.

```
private func addWKWebView(){
    let wv = WKWebView()
    view.addSubview(wv);
    wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    wv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:   view.widthAnchor  ).isActive = true
    wv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  view.heightAnchor ).isActive = true
    wv.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    wv.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

or Something like this:

```
private func addWKWebView(){
    let wv = WKWebView()
    view.addSubview(wv);
    wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    wv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  100).isActive = true
    wv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    wv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  100).isActive = true
    wv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
}
```

U need to play around with your constraints to set the WkWebView where u want.

Comment: Tried both, neither helped. In both cases the error still pops up.

Comment: Then might be ur other constraints. Why don't u add the WKWebView in the Storyboard so u can see in real time witch constraints are complaining.

Comment: Also u can try adding low priority to the 4 of them: let width = wv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  100)
        width.isActive = true
        width.priority = .defaultLow

Comment: I tried to add WKWebView in storyboard, the error doesn't go away. Also this is a brand new project with only the code I pasted above (i didn't add any new constraints in it).

Comment: What OS and device/Sim is this on? You do need to add constraints to the web view to position it. All the constraint warnings seem to be for the navigation bar and not for the web view or keyboard. There are numerous problems with the keyboard on iOS 11.

Comment: It didn't help for iOS 13.

Comment: I am seeing this in iOS 14 too using a UIViewControllerRepresentable in a SwiftUI app. Very annoying.

Comment: Same here. Ios 14. Still waiting for a fix

Comment: Same for iOS 15.5. Any news?

Comment: Same for iOS 16.1…

Answer (score -1):

I also have this problem when I need my custom-keyboard pop up.
Finally, all I need to do is change the html input-element's `eventType`: from `"touchstart"` to `"click"` .

Origin:

```
    function setUpEvent(elem, eventType, handler) {
        return (elem.attachEvent ? elem.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler)
            : ((elem.addEventListener) ? elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false) : null));
    }

    window.onload = function () {

        var input_ele = document.getElementById('YOUR_ELE_NAME');
        setUpEvent(input_ele, "touchstart", function (e) {

            //showKeyboard();//my personal function to show keyboard
        });
    }
```

And it works:

```
    function setUpEvent(elem, eventType, handler) {
        return (elem.attachEvent ? elem.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler)
            : ((elem.addEventListener) ? elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false) : null));
    }

    window.onload = function () {

        var input_ele = document.getElementById('YOUR_ELE_NAME');
        setUpEvent(input_ele, "click", function (e) {//change here

            //showKeyboard();//my personal function to show keyboard
        });
    }
```