# Remove the top toolbar from wkwebview keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, custom-keyboard

Im currently creating an app based out of a WKWebView and every time a keyboard pops up a toolbar above it shows like this: 
[image: Picture of keyboard with done bar]

I would like to remove this toolbar when the keyboard expands.

I have searched stack overflow and not found anything current about this topic (I've only found UIWebView), but if you find a post I missed I will be very thankful.

Im using swift.

All help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546394/hiding-keyboard-accessorybar-in-wkwebview

Comment: How do I implement that using swift?, thank you for your help

Comment: Swift version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853924/removing-wkwebview-accesory-bar-in-swift/33939584#33939584

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer on this post

Credit to Pavel above.

[Removing WKWebView Accesory bar in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853924/removing-wkwebview-accesory-bar-in-swift/33939584#33939584)

Add this code to your view controller:

```
fileprivate final class InputAccessoryHackHelper: NSObject {
    @objc var inputAccessoryView: AnyObject? { return nil }
}

extension WKWebView {
    func hack_removeInputAccessory() {
        print("s")
        guard let target = scrollView.subviews.first(where: {
            String(describing: type(of: $0)).hasPrefix("WKContent")
        }), let superclass = target.superclass else {
            return
        }

        let noInputAccessoryViewClassName = "\(superclass)_NoInputAccessoryView"
        var newClass: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString(noInputAccessoryViewClassName)

        if newClass == nil, let targetClass = object_getClass(target), let classNameCString = noInputAccessoryViewClassName.cString(using: .ascii) {
            newClass = objc_allocateClassPair(targetClass, classNameCString, 0)

            if let newClass = newClass {
                objc_registerClassPair(newClass)
            }
        }

        guard let noInputAccessoryClass = newClass, let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(InputAccessoryHackHelper.self, #selector(getter: InputAccessoryHackHelper.inputAccessoryView)) else {
            return
        }
        class_addMethod(noInputAccessoryClass.self, #selector(getter: InputAccessoryHackHelper.inputAccessoryView), method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
        object_setClass(target, noInputAccessoryClass)
    }
}
```

And then call it with

```
        webView.hack_removeInputAccessory()
```

After loading your view.